# How to limit DateTimePicker to half an hour?

Tags: winforms, telerik, datetimepicker

In a Windows application form, I need to put a time picker. I think I may select between System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker or Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadDateTimePicker. It's not to be used to select a date. It's to be used a time in a 24-hours. But the time should be aligned in half-an-hour, like 00:00, 00:30, 01:00 and so on. It should not be out of this. Eg. 20:45 or 05:53 are not acceptable.
Is there an option to limit such a control to these aligned values?

Comment: Doubt it.  Best you might do is handle the changed event(s) and round in the proper direction.  But that might infuriate your user who really wants 20:45.

Comment: don't think about user. there's no support for 20:45 anyway.
for this, i added handler for ValueChanged and ValueChanging and add the code: Value.AddMinutes(10); as test. no change in value occurs. it seems that the code is ignored!